# Count rows in Microsoft Excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Column A

Dog     
Apple
```

And some more words. But on the side of the table, I want to have a cell which tells me how many rows I have in Column A, and I want it to update as I add more rows. How could I do this using equations or functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=COUNTA(A:A)-1` will return the number of non-blank cells in Column A.

Comment: Ah, good one with the minus 1.

Comment: Don't put that formula in the column being counted. That will produce a circular reference error.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the header cell being counted you could just use:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your rows contain text you will need `{=COUNT(IF(A:A<>"",1,0))}`

It needs to be entered as an array formula. You might also need to subtract some value from this to account for header rows.